# Use Analytics in a WebView on Android and iOS

Tags: webview

I am writing to you for the first time. I would like to know if with the "webview" configuration (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/webview), it's good for hybrid apps and if you can track the transactions carried out on the institutional site, more precisely the payment takes place on the site and not within the app and understand that users who have converted arrive from the app and not from other channels. Thank you in advance for your opinion.
Elisa